# raw Resources Android filepath

Tags: android, database

I have database placed in raw folder and i need to load the database path when the apk is installed? Where it is? in /data/data/package_name/FILE ? I dont see it?

I work with extisting sqlite database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no path: It is a resource, so you need to reference is as such using `getResources()`.

You should, at the first run, copy it to the `/data/data/YOUR_APP_FOLDER/databases/YOUR_DB.db`

You can follow this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 1):

The files in the `raw` folder are packed in the application's APK file. To open one of these files, use `getResources().openRawResource(int id)`.

Comment: Yes. I know. But what's the path of the files when you install the application on the phone?

Comment: Is there a way of directly using the raw resource for reading the database? Or do I have to copy it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If you have a big database and you don't want to use too much space, maybe you could download the data on the first use.