# How to create configuration file for android application?

Tags: android

I want to develop one android frame work application for cites guide. I need one configuration file for all cites. That configuration file,I will change that configuration file for make various new  cities guide. How to create configuration file for my application.

Anybody know "how to create xml configuration file for our android application". Please give some idea about that.

Comment: I'm unsure of your question. By default, Android projects contain an AndroidManifest.xml that is used like the configuration file for the entire project. What more are you looking for? Or was that it?

Comment: @Jon,I known about Android Manifest.xml.I need one xml configuration file for layouts like my layout view  for application. for example i am using 3 pages for one city.I need same design but i will add or remove some future on that pages.so i need one xml configuration for that  pages.How to create configuration file.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlite database files for it. You have a native API to read and write those and on top of that a command line tool.

If you want to create an xml file instead, then it's no different than any other xml file (unless you are thinking about the SharedPreferences, which use an xml format to save the data, but I believe it's not the best API for your application).

Comment: @thanks for reply,I really  agree use sqlite database file,can u give elaborate details about How to make configure file using sqlite database for my application.

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742 and my answer here regarding copying the databases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231534/raw-resources-android-filepath/6231733#6231733

Answer (score 1):

That good sir is possible by using shared preferences