# I cannot find the file I am trying to read with my filereader class

Tags: android, file, text, filepath

I have created a file reader class called ECGFilereader which should open a .txt but when I debug it throws the FileNotFoundException to my Waveform class which uses the txt.file

Here is my coding below, any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

ECGFilereader.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ECGFilereader {

    public final static int numChannels = 12;
    public final static int numSamples = 500*6; //500 = fs so *6 for 6 seconds of data
    private File file;
    private Scanner scanner;
    int [] [] ecg = new int [numChannels] [numSamples];
    /*private String path;
    public ECGFilereader(String file_path){
        path = file_path;
    } */

     public ECGFilereader (String fname) throws FileNotFoundException 
     {
        file = new File("res/raw/ecg.txt");
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
    }

    public boolean ReadFile(Waveform[] waves) 
    {
        for (int m=0; m<numSamples && scanner.hasNextInt(); m++)
        {
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            for (int chan = 0; chan<numChannels && scanner.hasNextInt(); chan++)
            {
                ecg [chan] [m] = scanner.nextInt();     
            }
        }
        for (int chan=0; chan<numChannels; chan++)
            waves[chan].setSignal(ecg[chan]);
        return false;

    }

}
```

Waveform.java

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PointF;

public class Waveform {

    private int[] signal;


    public void setSignal(int [] x)
    {
        signal = new int[x.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < x.length; n++)
            signal[n] = x[n];
    }

    public void drawSignal(Canvas c, PointF pos)
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        //paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ECG_WaveI));
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);

            for (int n=1; n<ECGFilereader.numSamples; n++)
                path.lineTo(pos.x, (pos.y+signal[(int) n]));
                c.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access files in the res folder directly. As you want to access the file in the raw folder, try `getResource().openRawResource(int id)`

Look also here: [raw Resources Android filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231534/raw-resources-android-filepath/6231609#6231609)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it turns out that saving in the raw folder was completely wrong and I need to be storing the data on the sd card and I should be able to do that.